# How to discover if there is someone else connected to my wireless router?

Tags: wireless

I have a wireless router (WPA/WPA2) that is connected to my modem, so I can use wi-fi internet on my laptop. So, I'd like to know if there is any tool that allows me to discover if there is someone connected to my wireless router and if this tool allows me "kick" this person out of my network.

I'd prefer a multi-platform software, so I can use it in Ubuntu and Windows 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most WiFi routers have a browser-accessible admin interface (usually supplied with default passwords, that need changing...) showing connected clients. There is not, usually, a way to "kick them out", but there *is* a "MAC security" option. Not really so effective, since tools exist that allow modifying MACs of WiFis, but you can tell your router to only accept connections from your laptop's MAC address.

Since the interface is HTML/JS, it is naturally multiplatform. To "kick someone out", though, you need to reset the device (this also can be done remotely), thus kicking *everyone* out, and being then the only one to be able to get back in again (in such a scenario, *also* change the WiFi password!).

By default, most routers expose the interface on their own LAN IP, so you need only point the browser to, say, `http://192.168.0.1/` , or whatever your gateway address is.

Comment: Note that MAC filtering makes it harder to spot intruders: you're forcing an attacker to disguise themselves as one of your computers.

Answer (score 2):

some routers allow you to show attached devices, yours may have this option. You could always nmap your lan and find other devices that way, i'd do this from your lan rather than wireless in case isolation on wireless is enabled.

nmap -sS -Pn 192.168.0.x/24 or something like that

better just to choose use wpa2, random ssid and a very strong passphrase and make sure wps is disabled.